Seating arrangement around a circular table with certain restrictions
Five girls including Ramya and Five boys including Randhir are to be seated around a circular table such that no. two boys are adjacent and Ramya is not adjacent to Randhir. In how many ways this can be done?

My approach:-
All the girls can be seated on the chairs in $4!$ ways around the circular table.
Since no two boys are seated adjacent to each other, I took them to be seated on the chairs between two adjacent girls, since there are 5 seats available so the boys can occupy these 5 seats in $5!$ ways.
Now for the 2nd condition that Ramya and Randhir should not be seated together : Ramya can be seated on any of the 5 chairs which was initially selected for girls, correspondingly there will be 2 seats adjacent to her where Randhir would be seated.
so I am getting $4!*5!$ - $(5*2)$ ways , which is incorrect ! I am not able to understand the flaw in my approach, please help !

Your exclusion is done in a very weird way. Are you saying that there are only 10 ways for R-R to seat together? That seems very few to me. So, can you elaborate further?

No need for exclusion here...arrange the $5$ boys however.  That creates $5$ gaps each of which must contain exactly one girl.  Declare that Randhir  is at the head of the table, that establishes the rotation.  Pick a gap for Ramya, there are only three that meet the condition.  After that, you can assign freely.

@Calvin Lin Oh yes thats a very small number, I should take the arrangements of rest of the people as well... so maybe what I can do is first fix one R ,then rest of the girls can be arranged in 4! ways, also the second R has to be adjacent to this one so rest of the boys can be arranged in 4! ways, but the 2nd R can be on either side so 2*4!*4! should be deduced ?

thanks @lulu I got the answer by that approach :)) , but can you please help me with my method as well, does this exclusion which I have stated in above comment makes sense ?

If we assign Randhir seat $1$,  and fix the positions of the boys ($4!$ ways to do that), then there are $4!$ arrangements in which Ramya is in gap $1$ and $4!$ arrangements in which she is in gap $5$, with what I hope is obvious notation.

@VasuGupta I still have slight issues, so it's best for you to clarify in the writeup. EG To me, the universe of "sittings no two boys adjacent" is $5! \times 5!$ ways, but you seem to indicate it's $4! \times 5!$. $\quad$ And since you have the answer by another approach, you can see if your values match. If they do not, try to figure out what cases you could be missing / over-counting.

I suggest:  edit your post to include the solution you found by alternate means.  At a minimum, that will give a bright line test for any PIE computation.

Should say:  I am guessing that you meant to say that rotated arrangements are equivalent.  If that's wrong, it's easy to pass from one computation to the other.

The simple way is to fix Randhir at "head" of table, fix the rest of the boys in $4!$ ways, fix Ramya in $3$ ways, and the rest of the girl in$4!$ ways, so $4!\times 3\times 4! = 1728$ ways
But if you want to apply inclusion-exclusion, (again with Ranadhir at head of table) fix the boys in $4!$ ways, fix the girls in $(5!- 2\times 4!) =1728$
[Unconstrained girls can sit in $5!$ ways, - $2$ wrong seats for Ramya $\times 4!$ for the rest ]

This, of course takes seats as unnumbered as is the convention unless numbered seats are explicitly mentioned.
